# Unable to extract data with double pipe delimiter in Pig Script

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

I am trying to extract data which is pipe delimited in Pig. Following is my command

```
L = LOAD 'entirepath_in_HDFS/b.txt/part-m*' USING PigStorage('||');
```

Iam getting following error

```
2016-08-04 23:58:21,122 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 1, column 4> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[||]'
```

My input sample file has exactly 5 lines as following

```
POS_TIBCO||HDFS||POS_LOG||1||7806||2016-07-18||1||993||0
POS_TIBCO||HDFS||POS_LOG||2||7806||2016-07-18||1||0||0
POS_TIBCO||HDFS||POS_LOG||3||7806||2016-07-18||1||0||5
POS_TIBCO||HDFS||POS_LOG||4||7806||2016-07-18||1||0||0
POS_TIBCO||HDFS||POS_LOG||5||7806||2016-07-18||1||0||19.99
```

I tried several options like using the backslash before delimiter(\||,\|\|) but everything failed. Also, I tried with schema but got the same error.I am using Horton works(HDP2.2.4) and pig (0.14.0).

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800108/pig-script-failed-to-validate-java-lang-runtimeexception-could-not-instantiate/38803017#38803017

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this case, and by checking `PigStorage` [code source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.8.3/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.java), i think `PigStorage` argument should be parsed into only one character.

So we can use this code instead:

```
L0 = LOAD 'entirepath_in_HDFS/b.txt/part-m*' USING PigStorage('|');
L = FOREACH L0 GENERATE $0,$2,$4,$6,$8,$10,$12,$14,$16;
```

Its helpful if you know how many column you have, and it will not affect performance because it's map side.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. Actually our data might have single pipe. So the source is sending data delimited by double pipe. Is there any way to include double pipe as delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

When you load data using PigStorage, It only expects single character as delimiter.
However if still you want to achieve this you can use **MyRegExLoader**-

```
REGISTER '/path/to/piggybank.jar'
A = LOAD '/path/to/dataset' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader('||') 
      as (movieid:int, title:chararray, genre:chararray);
```

Comment: where to find the piggybank.jar?