# Load File delimited by double colon :: in pig

Tags: apache-pig

Following is a sample dataset delimited by double colon(::).

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
```

I want to extract three fields from above data set as movieID,title and genre. I have written following code for that

```
movies = LOAD 'location/of/dataset/on/hdfs ' 
using PigStorage('::')
as 
(MovieID:int,title:chararray,genre:chararray);
```

But i am getting following error

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to  parse:  
 <file script.pig, line 1, column 9> pig script failed to validate:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[::]'
```

Comment: The community [recently discussed ASAP begging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and has firmly agreed it is not acceptable. Please do not add this into your questions.

Comment: When you load data using PigStorage, It only expects single character as delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

Use [MyRegExloader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MyRegExLoader.html): You will need piggybank.jar for this.

```
REGISTER '/path/to/piggybank.jar'
A = LOAD '/path/to/dataset' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader('([^\\:]+)::([^\\:]+)::([^\\:]+)') 
      as (movieid:int, title:chararray, genre:chararray);
```

> Output :
>
> (1,Toy Story (1995),Animation|Children's|Comedy)