# How to use "::" seperator using pig

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2, bigdata

I have a file which consists of file.dat below:

```
1::Heat (1995)::Action|Crime|Thriller
2::Sabrina (1995)::Comedy|Romance
3::Tom and Huck (1995)::Adventure|Children's
```

now i am using my pig script to load a file:

```
input = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:54310/file.dat' USING PigSCript(':',':') as (id:int, name:chararray, generes:chararray);
```

but i am getting output like this

```
(1,,Heat (1995))
(2,,Sabrina (1995))
(3,,Tom and Huck (1995))
```

I am unable to understand where the problem occurs. Can anyone give me suggestions to solve this issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800108/pig-script-failed-to-validate-java-lang-runtimeexception-could-not-instantiate/38803017#38803017 --
 DUPLICATE ..see answer

Comment: thank you...solved